# Rails 3.1.0 Problems using haml - Missing template error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm trying to use haml in my project, I have a controller class and a view template, .html.haml

Here is my gemfile:

```
source  "http://rubygems.org"
#use Haml for templates
gem 'haml' '3.1.6'
#use Ruby debugger
group :development, :test do
gem 'ruby-debug19'
end
group :assets do
gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

I ran **bundle install** and restarted rails server many times, but haml doesn't even appear in **bundle show**.

I updated haml using gem, still no result.

**haml --rails** doesn't work - invalid option

vendor/plugins folder is empty

If I run rails server and open "http://localhost:3000/myindex", which I have a controller and a view template for, I get template error

```
Missing template movies/index, application/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
```

haml isn't there in handlers at all.

I tried to add

```
config.generators do |g|
      g.template_engine :haml
     end
```

to config/application.rb. Didn't work

Searched the web a whole day, read a lots of suggestions, but none of them helped.

bundle just refuses to install haml gem properly. Without indicating it as error. It simply ignores the gem.

Oh, and I ran **haml index.html.haml** on my template: html is generated perfectly. I made it very simple for test purposes.

Rails v: 3.1.0

Ruby v: 1.9.2p290

haml v: 3.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause.
I've created a new file "gemfile" when I had to edit existing "Gemfile", case-sensitive! 
So bundle just was reading a wrong file.

Answer (score 4):

Use `haml-rails` instead of `haml`. And delete the version string or add a comma:

```
gem 'haml-rails'
# or potentially
gem 'haml-rails', '3.1.6'
```

Comment: And you don't need the `config.generators` stuff.

Comment: here is my new gemfile:  source  "http://rubygems.org"
#use Haml for templates
gem 'haml-rails'
#use Ruby debugger
group :development, :test do
gem 'ruby-debug19'
end
group :assets do
gem 'therubyracer'
end

Comment: bundle install didn't install anything new, bundle show didn't show haml=(

Comment: can you paste your full `Gemfile`, `Gemfile.lock` and output of `bundle` somewhere (maybe gist.github.com) and link it here?

Comment: i can only paste a code here, I don't know how to upload file on gits via text-only terminal=(

Comment: gemfile: https://raw.github.com/gist/2892698/8bb4e18c22e9ef3943cb184122973fbeecc9570b/Gemfile